# How to Setup Incremental Backups on oVirt?

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, redhat, snapshot, ovirt

I just installed oVirt manager and node. After doing some reading I saw some articles mentioning ***incremental backups***. Is this feature available? I can't seem to find any instructions on how to use it. All I'm coming across is instructions for **snapshots* which isn't what I'm looking to use.

I'm looking for solutions on **backing up my oVirt virtual machines**. I'd appreciate any assistance or articles explaining how to setup incremental backups with oVirt.

Comment: What do you expect? What does incremental mean to you compared to snapshots?

Comment: oVirt sucks I moved on from this

Comment: Why does it suck? It's working very well. Don't just put random comments here without justification :)

Comment: Matter of opinion but the lack of sufficient documentation and number of users in the industry proved to be the downfall for me. The ovirt site does little to organize its data and is all over the place.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-virtualization/ ?